# As with Windows work on a Mac in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

I apologize in advance for not quite the correct question.

I doing cross-platform mobile development, Appcelerator (Titanium) on my Windows PC: 
http://www.appcelerator.com/

Such programs enough, so this question applies to them. There is another computer - a MacBook with Xcode installed. MacBook is on the same network as the computer on Windows. Specific question: is it possible to link both computers that appcelerator could compile project under the connected iphone/Ipad ?

There is a variant with PAserver, which is already installed on the macbook and listens to a specific port, but I don't have a clue how to organize work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can't compile an app for iPhone from Windows machine by connecting to your Mac machine port.

Need to setup the Appcelerator environment in both the machines. From Windows machine, you can build for android and windows apps. And, from MacOS you can build for iPhone/iPad apps. Of course, Mac also supports building apps for Android as well.